# React Prop Types Different Required Props Depending on Flag

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a React component that gets a configuration object as a prop, it looks something like this:

```
{
    active: true,
    foo: {
         bar: 'baz'
    }
}
```

In some cases, I want to disable the feature that the component displays by passing in a different object with `active: false`, like this:

```
{
    active: false
}
```

This works fine and is not the problem.

However, I also want to make sure that client code that uses my component supplies the proper configuration object:

- if active is true, foo is required
- if active is false, foo is optional and does not need to be provided

**How do I define prop types for a case like this?**

I've tried:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    config: PropTypes.oneOf([
        {
            active: false
        },
        PropTypes.shape({
            active: true,
            foo: PropTypes.shape({
                bar: PropTypes.string.isRequired
            })
        }).isRequired
    ]).isRequired
};
```

But this gives me the following warning:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `config` of value `[object Object]` supplied to `MyComponent`, expected one of [{"active":true},null].
>
> in MyComponent

I know why this does not work: it's because `PropTypes.oneOf` does not expect dynamic prop type matchers as values, but simply an array of valid arguments.

The question is, is there a way to make this work?

I've made a runnable sandbox example where you can try out the example code above: https://codesandbox.io/s/n9o0wl5zlj

Comment: Check out https://github.com/thejameskyle/react-required-if - looks like it does what you want.

Comment:  Cool, that works, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `wgcrouch` suggested in his answer, the `prop-types` lib does not provide this functionality, so using a custom prop type is the way to go.

Fortunately, as Tom Fenech pointed out in the comments to my question, this particular problem has already been solved, so there is an npm package available that I've used: [react-required-if](https://github.com/thejameskyle/react-required-if).

My working solution looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import requiredIf from 'react-required-if';

function MyComponent({ config }) {
  if (!config.active) {
    return null;
  }
  return <h1>Hello {config.foo.bar}!</h1>;
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  config: PropTypes.shape({
    active: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    foo: requiredIf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        bar: PropTypes.string.isRequired
      }),
      props => props.active
    )
  })
};

export default MyComponent;
```

→ See [updated code sandbox with solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3oxj1jp5v).

Answer (score 6):

You could use a custom propType (documented on propTypes site) function eg:

```
MyComponent.proptypes = {
    active: PropTypes.bool,
    foo: function(props, propName, componentName) {
        if (props['active'] && !props[propName]) {
            return new Error(
                `${propName} is required when active is true in ${componentName}.`
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment:  Thanks, this is indeed the way to go, but there is already an npm package available that solved this problem, as suggested in the comments, so I've posted my own answer with a working solution using that.